# How to check node authorship info in views

Tags: views, 6

I want to show users their published articles in a block. Those articles have their author name set in by Admin manually while the articles are created by Admin on behalf of the users.

In views I don't find any field in Node to compare authorship of the node with logged in user.

I've found a related article: http://drupal.org/node/228959
but no idea about how to look for following point in the article:

```
Go to 'Arguments' and select "User: UID is Author" and set the default
value to 'Return Page not found'.
```

I don't see "User: UID is Author". I only see "User:UID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to your view of `User: Current`.  This will filter the nodes to ones created by the current user.

[image: User: Current Views Filter]

Comment: Laxman13 you are genius.

Comment: Your method works. I've done another way, not sure if it is correct: In Arguments I added User:Uid then in "Action to take if argument is not present" selected "Provide default argument". Then "Default argument type": User ID from logged in user. And this seems to be working. Is this too right?

Comment: Yes that should work as well